# Underlining button title xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uibutton

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone: How to Display Underlined Text in a Button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645393/iphone-how-to-display-underlined-text-in-a-button)
>   [underline text in UIlabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711297/underline-text-in-uilabel)

I have a section im my app like this...Not a member? Signup here, where here is a custom button of transparent background and upon clicking takes the user to a url in safari. Now what i need is i want to make this button title underlined so that it looks like a hyperlink. Thanks

Comment: You're gonna have to implement the underlining yourself. You can also make a custom button. Some good pointers can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2711297/653513

Comment: Or a simpler solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565407/underline-uilabel-text

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If the button title will be static, the easiest way is probably to create an image of the text (underlined) and use the image as the button image on a custom button.

Comment: this would be the most easiest and quickest solution i guess and also it would not hurt apple's HIG i hope.

Comment: or to underline the text using an attributed string in code....

Answer (score 0):

You can set a custom label for titleLabel in the UIButton and create underline in the custom UILabel:
[Underline text in UIlabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711297/underline-text-in-uilabel/2711587#2711587)